# VSCode open Java Code but can't find/show Java version on the status bar, and the Java Projects says:No java projects found in the current workspace

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, version

[So I'm opening this Java Code from a College Project but it doesn't detect the Java Language (appears JavaSE-11 on others and on the left menu 'Java Projects', it just says it doesn't detect any at all.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIWDL.png)

Anyway, kinda lost, when I try to run I get this message:

cmd /C ""C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin\java.exe" -cp C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\024a910f1bbcd79a81d5e3f26e0eb2e2\redhat.java\jdt_ws\jdt.ls-java-project\bin br.pucrs.adt.tests.progs.TestaLista "
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
ListSimpleLinkedFull cannot be resolved to a type
ListDoubleLinked cannot be resolved to a type
ListDoubleLinked cannot be resolved to a type
ListSimpleLinkedFull cannot be resolved to a type
ListSimpleLinkedFull cannot be resolved to a type
at br.pucrs.adt.tests.progs.TestaLista.main(TestaLista.java:36)

When in other projects I have no problem with this, it shows the Java SE-11 version and the 'My Projects' on the left: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvq4Z.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide a sample project for the issue or some more screenshot showing the folder structure, which might be helpful